# How to route the value of a JS variable to an HTML Div?

Tags: javascript, variables

Hey guys I'm totally new here and need help on an assignment. Last week we created a simple JS program that converts decimal to binary (without using parseint). The new assignment is to prompt the user for a decimal number, then display the resulting binary number in 8 separate div elements.

Although there might have been a more succinct way to do the conversion, here is what I did within javascript. For clarification I named the variables with respect to their corresponding base two power (2^7 place, 2^6 place, etc)

```
var seven = 0;
var six = 0;
var five = 0;
var four = 0;
var three = 0;
var two = 0;
var one = 0;
var zero = 0;

var input = document.getElementById("dec").value;

if (input < 128) {
  seven = 0;
}

if (input > 128) {
  input = input % 128;
  seven = 1;
}

if (input < 64) {
  six = 0;
}

if (input > 64) {
  input = input % 64;
  six = 1;
}

if (input < 32) {
  five = 0;
}

if (input > 32) {
  input = input % 32;
  five = 1;
}

if (input < 16) {
  four = 0;
}

if (input > 16) {
  input = input % 16;
  four = 1;
}

if (input < 8) {
  three = 0;
}

if (input > 8) {
  input = input % 8;
  three = 1;
}

if (input < 4) {
  two = 0;
}

if (input > 4) {
  input = input % 4;
  two = 1;
}

if (input < 2) {
  one = 0;
}

if (input > 2) {
  input = input % 2;
  one = 1;
}

if (input < 1) {
  zero = 0;
}

if (input = 1) {
  zero = 1;
}
```

Here is what I've done in html. (We use codepen.io, which does not require body tags)

```
<form>
  <input type="number" id="dec" min="0" max="255" step="1" />
</form>

<div id="seventh">0</div>
<div id="sixth">0</div>
<div id="fifth">0</div>
<div id="fourth">0</div>
<div id="third">0</div>
<div id="second">0</div>
<div id="first">0</div>
<div id="zeroth">0</div>
```

So getting down to the real question, once the user inputs a decimal number and I have the binary units saved to their corresponding variables, how do I route the value of these variables to the div elements I created in HTML?

Thanks so much for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

plain javascript

```
document.getElementById("seventh").innerHTML = "ayo new text";
```

jquery

```
$('#seventh').text("ayo new text");
```

and since your going to be using variables substitute the string for that var.

```
document.getElementById("seventh").innerHTML = yourVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a [homework question (and thanks for being up front about that)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), I'll post a way to find your answer instead of just the answers. *Learning is all about discovery*.

What you're trying to do is change the `textContent` of a DOM node. This is pretty central to a lot of features of javascript applications, so it's useful to know [the ins and outs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686911/597122).

A great starting place is *always* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). MDN has phenomenal documentation for a lot of the technologies in the browser, and it's an invaluable resource for DOM and JavaScript.

If you search for `textContent` on MDN, it should show you some results that might link you to the docs for [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

[Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) in the DOM inherit from Node, so this is a good page to keep in your back pocket.

You'll notice in your code you have `getElementById()` which, as the name implies, will return an HTML Element.

Back to the Node.textContent page: note the sections titled **"Differences from innerText"** and **"Differences from innerHTML"**. It would be wise to scan these sections so you understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

you get the element instance via document.getElementId("elementname/id") then use the .innerHTML attribute to change the value of it

Comment: How does one change the value of it?

Comment: so if the element is called "example", then you would do document.getElementById("example).innerHTML = "I just changed the element's value"